# Getting ERR_CONNECTION_RESET while playing mp3 audio

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am using the following code:

```
var sound = new Audio(path);
sound.load();
```

Then I'm playing it. It starts playing about 10-15 seconds. But then it stops. The console on chrome shows an error:

localhost:8080/sounds/music.mp3 net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

What is the problem here? When opening file directly from browser, it loads and plays normally.

EDIT 1: that is happening only with chrome. Firefox and IE is playing music from start till end.

Comment: maximus, are you able to fix the issue? i know its too late to ask but i am facing same issue where in audio/video playing fine in Firefox/IE but Chrome is throwing net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error